# Storing parquet file in redis

Tags: python, redis, parquet, pyarrow

I want to know how I would store a parquet file as it is binary data in redis via python?

Background is, that I want check the fastest way of serving a parquet file of small size over the network. I believe object storage like s3 or any file system is slower. So it comes down to the fastest way of serving binary data over the network, but still have some database like
structure as storage layer. Probably the data needs to live in the memory on the server side to send it over network directly into the clients side memory.
(remember it is about small size files compressed with parquet around 30-50 Mb, so to big for simple file system reads and to small for big data technology, hdfs etc. )

Comment: The parquet format is binary (always).

Comment: Yes, why are you saying that? That is the question how to store binary data in redis with an example by using a parquet file...

Comment: I changed the question for people like you maybe misunderstanding it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay found it myself:

1. Use python Pandas to write as bytes into memory

   bytes_data = df.to_parquet()
2. Now having the compressed parquet format as bytes in memory one can send it to redis

   set("key", bytes_data)